# How credit/debit card chargebacks can be used

Tags: chargeback

Can someone explain to me what chargebacks are and how I can use it to get my money if I buy bitcoins with debit/credit card. I heard about this thing for first time when I started to use bitcoins and this is the only explanation why all the exchanges does not accept debit/credit cards. I know transaction in bitcoin is irreversible but I can use chargeback to get my money back. In the same way I can buy something other not bitcoins and chargeback my money again. Bitcoin is just a thing its not special, and if I cant use debitcard to pay bitcoins then I cant use debitcard to pay whatever.

Example:
I am buying potatoes form the shop its irreversible because potatoes are in my bag and I can use chargeback and get my money.

Where is the difference with bitcoins ?

Comment: seams here people just dont want to talk

Comment: Your question is not very clear. For example, your example does not make sense - why is a potato transaction irreversible? You can give the potatoes back if they're rotten or whatever. Why would you use chargeback to "get your money" when you already have the potatoes? You *paid* money for those potatoes.

Comment: Yes I paid money for potatoes and after get the potatoes I want to cheat and get money back. In fact to get potatoes without money. The same is with botcoins, I can buy Bitcoins with debitcard and after that nothing will happen. Why then noone accept debit cart and they blame chargebacks ?

Answer (score 0):

A chargeback happens when a credit card user disputes a transaction for some reason. Sometimes this might be due to defective goods, or goods that did not arrive, or that the legitimate user of the card did not make the transaction (that is, the credit card details where stolen and used fraudulently). When the chargeback happens, the credit card processor effectively takes back the money from the seller that you had previously paid using the card.

Transactions involving the sale of virtual currency (such as buying bitcoins) are particularly subject to abuse involving stolen credit card numbers. For somebody who has stolen credit card numbers, bitcoins are probably more useful than physical goods such as a sack of potatoes. In order to eliminate this risk, the seller of bitcoins does not permit bitcoins to be purchased with credit cards.